# javascript scroll to cursor: rect.top changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, position

I have a contenteditable div in a webpage and I'm trying to bring the cursor into view with the following code.  What I experience is that the cursor coordinates that are returned seem to jump around...usually the x value is fine but the y value alternates between the correct value and a very low one, resulting in the page scrolling too far up and then back to the correct place with alternating key presses/ calls.
Any insight is appreciated.  My javascript is:

```
function getCaretClientPosition() 
{ 
var element = document.getElementById('mydivcontent'); 
var x = 0, y = 0; 
var doc = element.ownerDocument; 
var win = doc.defaultView; 
var sel = win.getSelection(); 

  if (sel.rangeCount) 
  { 
    var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); 
    if (range.getBoundingClientRect) 
    { 
      var rects = range.getClientRects(); 
      if (rects.length > 0) 
      { x = rects[0].left; y = rects[0].top; } 
    } 
  } 

  win.scrollTo(x, y); 
  return x.toString()+'|'+ y.toString();
}
```

Called from the C# side each time a char is entered:
    var result = webview.EvaluateJavascript("getCaretClientPosition();");

the result will alternate as chars are entered eg: 24|645, 36|77, 48|645, 60|77... occasionally the x values alternate between highs and lows also

Answer (score 0):

> resulting in the page scrolling too far up and then back to the
>   correct place with alternating key presses/ calls.

You default `x` and `y` to `0` at the top of your code and only set `x` and `y` under certain conditions...yet you **always** do the `win.scrollTo(x, y)` maybe you only want to do that `scrollTo` if you've actually found a worthy `x` and `y`?

Comment: Thanks but I'm not getting a 0,0 result.  In fact I'm checking for that in my code behind and not scrolling to it.  As I said I'm getting a result which is usually a lower y value.  FWIW the context is a uiwebview in a xamarin iOS app...so the browser is Safari.

Comment: Hmm, ok. That's information that should be included in the question itself (you may want to edit it). I am not sure how you're "checking for that in [your] code behind" and not doing it, but that's also code you may want to include.